# Paypal with option useraction=commit not creating transaction

Tags: symfony, paypal

i installed ezsystems/payment-paypal-bundle on ibexa commerce as a payment provider with all config and useraction=commit. so the Customer logs in from Paypal and clicks on the Pay Now button. Paypal gives no error, everything seems to be successful and customer is redirected at the RETURNURL, but no transaction is created in the buyer or in the seller account.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to show a review page on return, and run DoExpressCheckoutPayment (or equivalent) after the payer confirms the payment on your site.  Setting useraction=commit will change the verbiage of the last button to say "Pay Now" instead of "Continue", indicating to the user that you are going to capture immediately (skipping the default review step) but this is only a wording change -- you still need to do a DoExpressCheckoutPayment (or newer API order capture/execution) to get a success orfailure response, and show the result.

It's worth noting that SetExpressCheckout / DoExpressCheckout payment are very old APIs....

The current v2/checkout/orders REST API does have similar capabilities if doing a redirect integration, but such redirecting is an old flow/  Keeping your site loaded and [using JS for the approval instead of a redirect](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) is always recommended nowadays (works with both current and old APIs).